# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python

[image]

In function mid(a, b), I cannot access value of object a, b such as x, y, z.
I think my class point composed of public property.
How can I access to property x, y, z?
In function mid(a,b), why my interpreter regard a,b as a tuple?
And why python show those 3 error to me?
I think my logic is perfect, but I can't find my fatal things

```py
import math

points = []


class point:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def printInfo(self):
        print(f"x={self.x} | y={self.y} | z={self.z}")


def my_length(a, b):
    length = math.sqrt(
        math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2) + math.pow(a.z - b.z, 2)
    )
    return length


def mid(a, b):
    x1 = a.x * 0.5 + b.x * 0.5
    y1 = a.y * 0.5 + b.y * 0.5
    z1 = a.z * 0.5 + b.z * 0.5
    return point(x1, y1, z1)


def my_input():

    global points

    for i in range(4):
        x, y, z = map(int, input().split())
        points.append(point(x, y, z))
    return


def direction(p, q, r, s, flag):
    if flag == "L1":
        # L1에 있는점을 왼쪽으로 이동했을때 거리 len_1
        len_1 = my_length(mid(p, mid(p, q)), mid(r, s))
        # L1에 있는점을 오른쪽으로 이동했을때 거리 len_2
        len_2 = my_length(mid(mid(p, q), q), mid(r, s))
        if len_1 > len_2:
            return "Right"
        elif len_1 < len_2:
            return "Left"
        else:
            return "change"
    elif flag == "L2":
        # L2에 있는점을 왼쪽으로 이동했을때 거리 len_1
        len_1 = my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, mid(r, s)))
        # L2에 있는점을 오른쪽으로 이동했을때 거리 len_2
        len_2 = my_length(mid(p, q), mid(mid(r, s), s))
        if len_1 > len_2:
            return "Right"
        elif len_1 < len_2:
            return "Left"
        else:
            return "change"


def my_sol(p, q, r, s, prev_l, flag):

    ep = 0.0001
    # end condition
    next = []
    next.append(my_length(mid((p, q), q), mid(r, s)))
    next.append(my_length(mid(p, mid(p, q)), mid(r, s)))
    next.append(my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, mid(r, s))))
    next.append(my_length(mid(p, q), mid(mid(r, s), s)))

    if abs(min(next) - prev_l) < 0.05:
        print(my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, s)))
        return my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, s))

    # flag = 1이면, 직선 L1에 있는 점p를 오른쪽으로 옮길지 왼쪽으로 옮길지 정함
    if flag == "L1":
        #    오른쪽으로 가야한다
        if direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "Right":
            my_sol(mid(p, q), q, r, s, next[0], "L1")
        #    왼쪽으로 가야한다
        elif direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "Left":
            my_sol(p, mid(p, q), r, s, next[1], "L1")
        elif direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "change":
            my_sol(p, q, r, s, my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, s)), "L2")
    # flag = -1 이면, 직선 L2에 있는 점q를 오른쪽으로 옮길지 왼쪽으로 옮길지 정함
    else:
        #    오른쪽으로 가야한다
        if direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "Right":
            my_sol(p, q, r, mid(r, s), next[2], "L2")
        #    왼쪽으로 가야한다
        elif direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "Left":
            my_sol(p, q, mid(r, s), s, next[3], "L2")
        elif direction(p, q, r, s, flag) == "change":
            my_sol(p, q, r, s, my_length(mid(p, q), mid(r, s)), "L2")
    # flag = -1 이면, 직선 L2에 있는 점q를 오른쪽으로 옮길지 왼쪽으로 옮길지 정함


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_input()
    # setting
    a, b, c, d = points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3]
    my_sol(a, b, c, d, 0, "L1")
```

Comment: Start with `print(a, b)` before the line that errors out to see what your values are. I'd guess somewhere you have a trailing `,`, which turns some value into a tuple. It's pretty hard to find that in this mass of commas and parentheses though. That's a lot easier for you with some debugging and backtracking.

Comment: thank you.... I made code so difficult.. its my fault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this is a typo

```
next.append(my_length(mid((p, q), q), mid(r, s)))
```

Your call to `mid` is passing a tuple, `(p, q)` as the first argument instead of a point. I imagine that should be `mid(mid(p,q), q)`

```
next.append(my_length(mid(mid(p, q), q), mid(r, s)))
```

Comment: thank you I think I made code difficult to read.... I finally found it